# Python Pandas calculate total volume with last article volume

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following problem and do not know how to solve it in a perfomant way:

Input Pandas DataFrame:

| timestep | article | volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 35 | 1 | 20 |
| 37 | 2 | 5 |
| 123 | 2 | 12 |
| 155 | 3 | 10 |
| 178 | 2 | 23 |
| 234 | 1 | 17 |
| 478 | 1 | 28 |

Output Pandas DataFrame:

| timestep | volume |
| --- | --- |
| 35 | 20 |
| 37 | 25 |
| 123 | 32 |
| 178 | 53 |
| 234 | 50 |
| 478 | 61 |

Calculation Example for timestep 478:
28 (last article 1 volume) + 23 (last article 2 volume) + 10 (last article 3 volume) = 61

What ist the best way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `ffill`:

```
#sort if needed
df = df.sort_values("timestep")

df["volume"] = (df["volume"].where(df["article"].eq(1)).ffill().fillna(0) + 
                df["volume"].where(df["article"].eq(2)).ffill().fillna(0))
output = df.drop("article", axis=1)

>>> output
  timestep  volume
0        35    20.0
1        37    25.0
2       123    32.0
3       178    43.0
4       234    40.0
5       478    51.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Group By article & Take last element & Sum

```
 df.groupby(['article']).tail(1)["volume"].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df["new_volume"] = (
    df.loc[df["article"] != df["article"].shift(-1), "volume"]
        .reindex(df.index, method='ffill')
        .shift()
      + df["volume"]
).fillna(df["volume"])

df
```

Output:

```
   timestep  article  volume  new_volume
0        35        1      20        20.0
1        37        2       5        25.0
2       123        2      12        32.0
3       178        2      23        43.0
4       234        1      17        40.0
5       478        1      28        51.0
```

#### Explained:

Find the last record of each group by checking the 'article' from the previous row, then reindex that series aligning to the original dataframe and fill forward and shift to the next group with that 'volume'.  And this to the current row's 'volume' and fill that first value with the original 'volume' value.

Comment: Yes, nice solution. but this only works for 2 items, but there can be n items. See my change of post

Comment: @sekr What's the reasoning for dropping Article 3?

Comment: I need the new total volume for every change to the timestep. To do this, the last volume of each article must always be added up. However, I don't know how, except with multiple loops

Answer (score 0):

You can set group number of consecutive `article` by [`.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html).  Then get the value of previous group last item by [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`GroupBy.last()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html).  Finally, add `volume` with this previous last, as follows:

```
# Get group number of consecutive `article`
g = df['article'].ne(df['article'].shift()).cumsum() 

# Add `volume` to previous group last
df['volume'] += g.sub(1).map(df.groupby(g)['volume'].last()).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   timestep  article  volume
0        35        1      20
1        37        2      25
2       123        2      32
3       178        2      43
4       234        1      40
5       478        1      51
```

---

**Breakdown of steps**

Previous group last values:

```
g.sub(1).map(df.groupby(g)['volume'].last()).fillna(0, downcast='infer')


0     0
1    20
2    20
3    20
4    43
5    43
Name: article, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yes, nice solution. but this only works for 2 items, but there can be n items. See my change of post